# Can I use two identical Components?

Tags: vue.js

In some cases, you want to call a popup or non-popup

```
<template>
<!-- popup -->
<v-dialog v-model="popupFlag">
    <A :prop-option="option">
</v-dialog>


<!-- main -->
<div v-if="!popupFlag">
    <B :prop-option="option">
</div>
</template>

import A from "C.vue"
import B from "C.vue"

export default {

    props: {
        popupFlag: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        }
    },
    data() {
        return: {
            option: 'blah'
        }
    }
    
}
```

I configured the code as below, is it the right code?
Can I use the same component? ( C.vue )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can use the same component multiple times in the parent component. Each time you insert it into your template, it creates a new instance of the component. So, in your case, your code could be simplified like this:

```
<template>
  <!-- main -->
  <div v-if="!popupFlag">
    <C :prop-option="option" />
  </div>

  <!-- popup -->
  <div v-else>
    <C :prop-option="option" />
  </div>
</template>

...
import C from "C.vue"
...
```

Or, an even simpler approach would be:

```
<C :prop-option="popupFlag ? optionForPopup : optionForMain" />
```

This way, you can efficiently reuse the same component with different options based on the `popupFlag`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same component twice without importing it twice.

The `return` statement in `data()` is fixed by removing the colon because it returns an object.

```
<template>
  <!-- popup -->
  <div v-if="popupFlag">
    <C :prop-option="option"></C>
  </div>

  <!-- main area -->
  <div v-else>
    <C :prop-option="option"></C>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import C from 'C.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        C
    },
    props: ...,
    data() {
        return {
            option: 'blah'
        }
    }   
}
</script>
```